# how to create clickable elements inside an imageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to clickable elements inside an imageView in my android app but am not finding any way to do that.

My goal is to do the same thing as in this website: https://listed.life/hubbox-flyer/

I hope you understand my request, thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: *`I hope you understand my request`* yes But what did you tried so far? any efforts from your side

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to make the ImageView clickable? If that's the case, you should set an OnClickListener.

In your .xml file you give an id to your imageView, let's say `android:id="@+id/iv_product"`

Then, inside your Activity, you find your imageView with findViewById like this:
`ImageView imageView= findViewById(R.id.iv_product)`

Finally, you set the OnClickListener:

`imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         // Do whatever you want here
    }
 });`

Comment: thank you for the answer but what I want it to make certain parts of the imageView clickable just like in the website https://listed.life/hubbox-flyer/

Comment: I am afraid that what you say doesn't make sense. All "imageViews" in the webpage you provided are clickable. Anyway, perhaps you need to implement a Layout which will consist of a clickable ImageView together with a TextView or another ImageView that is not clickable...

Answer (score 0):

use this code`

```
 <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/image"
               android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity ="center"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
               android:background="#e6e4e4"
               android:visibility="visible"
               android:layout_height="200dp" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

and then add setOnClickListener on button.
For more information check android intro slider code.